# How to calculate the voltage gain in this picture?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHVOJ1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know that by using \$A_v=-G_mR_{out}\$, and \$G_m=\frac{I_{out}}{V_{in}}\$, we can get the voltage gain of this circuit.

After the small signal simplification, I got:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB6pOC.png)</sup>

So, as node 1 is 0 volt, there is no current goes thru \$M_2\$, then \$I_{out}\approx g_{m1}V_{in}\$ ? So that \$G_m=g_{m1}\$ which is the \$g_m\$ of \$M_1\$? Also, the \$R_{out}\$ is \$R_{02}\$, and is the voltage gain of this circuit \$-g_{m1}R_{02}\$?
Thank you!!!!

-------------------------------------------------------UPDATE

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSPhp2.png)</sup>

What about this circuit?

After the small signal, I got:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL375l.png)</sup>

Comment: This is not an amplifier. It's just a MOSFET incinerator.

Comment: Are you comfortable thinking about loadlines, that involve a resistor. Multiplying the discrete resistor by the gm produces an estimated gain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The voltage gain is 0, because \$V_{out}\$ is connected directly to a voltage source, so its voltage will never vary, no matter what signal is present at the input.

Furthermore, M2 will probably catch fire, because its gate and drain are connected directly to the Vcc supply, which will cause a large current to flow through the FET, while it also must drop the full Vcc voltage.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**
This answer is for the updated schematic 
 **Assumptions:**
The quiescent voltages keeps the MOSFETS in saturation (pinch off) region

[image]

Here assuming that there is channel length modulation The gain at the first stage is \$-g_{m1}r_{o1}\$ . Since the voltage gain of the next stage \$M_{2}\$ depends on the load resistance \$R_{load}\$.
 So the effective gain is \$g_{m1}g_{m2}r_{o1}(r_{o2}||R_{load})\$

Comment: Derwin - are you aware that both drain nodes are connected to the power supply Vcc ?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this in the answer .                                      My answer assumed that the 
          mosfets are biased properly (I know there is no feedback  shown  but i assumed that the quiescent voltages maintained them in saturation  )
         Also this answer is for the updated circuit where he used current sources

Comment: OK - in case of current sources, you are right. But it is - as you know - a fundamental difference if I use voltage or current sources.

Comment: Yep I agree with that in case of voltage source the gain is zero and if Vcc is large the FETs are done